# Call global function with same name as class method?

Tags: c++

I have global functions which have the same names as member methods. Both are to be used in the same scope. How do I distinguish them? Is adding a prefix 'g' to global functions the convention? I know it is conventional for global variables, but not sure if so for global functions.

Comment: You can use different namespace for global functions

Comment: Are we to assume they have not only the same name but the same call-signature as well (you didn't say).

Comment: Use ::function to reach the global one, and yourClassName::function for the class member function. But far better to use namespaces.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to change the function name to use them.

As the comments say, you can fully qualify the function e.g.

```
void foo()
{
}

class Bar
{
  void foo()
  {
  }

  void wibble()
  {
    ::foo();
  }
};
```

`::` means look in global scope